# Nginx config SSL Error

Tags: nginx

nginx won't start.
I'm using the turnkeylinux NGINX image for VMware and installed the NGINX module for the included webmin. this is the printout when I try to start NGINX via ssh:

```
root@nginx-php-fastcgi ~# nginx
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or dire
ctory:fopen('/etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)                           
root@nginx-php-fastcgi ~# nginx -s reload
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or dire
ctory:fopen('/etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)                           
root@nginx-php-fastcgi ~#
```

Comment: Nginx clearly says that cannot find a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have to either switch SSL off for your website in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or make sure the SSL-certificate file exists in the `/etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt` path and is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Good pratice would be to TEST the configuration before starting or attempting to reload anything nginx -- and that also goes for 'stuff in general'.

```
# nginx -t
```

would most certainly have avoided this situation.

Doing `nginx -t && nginx -s reload` (as written) performs the check against the config and only after a successful return value does it attempts to reload the config.

Adding it as a shell alias ain't a bad idea if you run the damn thing as much as i do at times.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, path / ownership / permissions are ok :/
try change cert location, restart whole server...

After 1 hour of investigating that was happend:

1. remove PROPER path to .pem from nginx config
2. add it again
   everythink works XD

Comment: You most likely copy/pasted a path containing bad characters - like tabs - in your first attempt. Many things are invisible... `cat -A nginx.conf` would show you all weird characters, if any, in a file.

Answer (score 0):

For future seekers: check your file extensions.

It might not show .txt if you are using windows server. This was the problem for me.